# Azure DevOps I can't get 1800 minutes of MS Hosted

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had set up a free account on Azure DevOps and tried to run a simple pipeline and have the following message

"This agent request is not running because you have reached the maximum number of requests that can run for parallelism type 'Microsoft-hosted Private'. Current position in queue: 1"

I clicked on "setting" -> "parallel Jobs" to see if I had a job in execution and discovered that I don't have 1800 min of MS Hosted.

[image]

Does someone know what's have happened? The Azure DevOps site says that every free account has 1800 min for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft have removed the grant of free minutes as it was being abused.

You can apply to get your minutes reinstated.

Full details are here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-184-update and here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/